# How to read files from a folder in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, io

I want to read some `jpg` files from a folder using c++. I've searched the internet, and couldn't find a solution to this. I don't want to use Boost or other libraries, but just write it in C++ function. For instance, I have 40 images, named by `"01.jpg, 02.jpg,...40.jpg"` in my folder, I want to give the folder address, and read these 40 images and save them one by one in a vector. I tried several times, but failed. I am using Visual Studio. Could someone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: try findfirstfile and findnextfile in sdk or cfilefind in mfc.

Comment: How about starting with `for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) { ... }`? Then read about [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: See answers for this question for how to do it using Win32 APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068475/recursive-hard-disk-search-with-findfirstfile-findnextfile-c

Comment: Is the question about how you generate strings for fixed filenames, or is this question about how to read directory contents?

Comment: It is about how to read directory contents, here in my case, they are ".jpg" files. I think I have solved this, by making use of "sprintf_s" function in visual studio. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize based on your comment that you have come up with a workable solution using [`_sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Microsoft likes to promote this as a safer alternative to [`sprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and that is true if you're writing your program in C.  In C++ however there are *much safer* ways to build a string that don't require you to manage a buffer or have knowledge of it's maximum size. If you want to be idiomatic about it I recommend you drop using [`_sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and use the tools provided by the C++ Standard Library.

The solution presented below uses a simple [`for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/for) loop and [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to create the filename and load the image. I've also included the use of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for lifetime management and ownership semantics. Depending on how the images are going to be used you may need to use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

// Just need something for example
struct Image
{
    Image(const std::string& filename) : filename_(filename) {}
    const std::string filename_;
};

std::unique_ptr<Image> LoadImage(const std::string& filename)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Image>(new Image(filename));
}

void LoadImages(
    const std::string& path,
    const std::string& filespec,
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>>& images)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        std::stringstream filename;

        // Let's construct a pathname
        filename
            << path
            << "\\"
            << filespec
            << std::setfill('0')    // Prepends '0' for images 1-9
            << std::setw(2)         // We always want 2 digits
            << i
            << ".jpg";

        std::unique_ptr<Image> img(LoadImage(filename.str()));
        if(img == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to load image");
        }
        images.push_back(std::move(img));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>>    images;

    LoadImages("c:\\somedirectory\\anotherdirectory", "icon", images);

    // Just dump it
    for(auto it = images.begin(); it != images.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it)->filename_ << std::endl;
    }
}
```