# Weird bug with routine to list files recursively

Tags: c, unix

Can anybody spot what I am missing here?  This block of code is supposed to recursively access directories and store the directory path and the path of the files in it. It will fprintf() a true if the file is a directory and a false if the file is not a directory. Weird part is that the printf routine for fileName works fine but when its time to fprintf fileName to a file, it just prints a newline where its supposed to print fileName.

```
/* List the files in "dir_name". */
static void listDir(const char *dirName)
{
DIR *dir;

/* 
 * Open the directory specified by "dirName". 
 */

dir = opendir(dirName);

/* 
 * Check it was opened. 
 */
if (!dir) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
            dirName, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (1) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    const char *dir_name;

    /* 
     * "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". 
     */
    entry = readdir(dir);
    if (!entry) {
        /* 
         * There are no more entries in this directory, so break out of the while loop. 
         */
        break;
    }
    dir_name = entry->d_name;
    char fileName[PATH_MAX];
            // Assign fileName to path if the file is not a directory
    if (entry->d_type != DT_DIR) {
        if (strcmp(dirName, "/") != 0) {
            snprintf(fileName, PATH_MAX,
                                   "%s/%s", dirName, dir_name);
        } else {
            snprintf(fileName, PATH_MAX,
                                   "%s%s", dirName, dir_name);
        }
    }
    /* Access directory and leave out /. and /.. in the process
     */

    if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {

        /* 
         * Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. 
         */

        if (strcmp(dir_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(dir_name, ".") != 0) {
            int path_length;
            char path[PATH_MAX], indexPath[PATH_MAX];
            if (strcmp(dirName, "/") != 0) {
                path_length = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX,
                                       "%s/%s", dirName, dir_name);
            } else {
                path_length = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX,
                                       "%s%s", dirName, dir_name);
            }
            strcpy(indexPath, path);
            strcat(indexPath, "/masterIndex.db");
            FILE *fp;
            if ((fp = fopen(indexPath, "a")) == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot open file\n");
                return;
            }

            printf("File: %s\n      (TRUE)\n", path);
            printf("File: %s\n      (FALSE)\n", fileName); // This routine prints fileName correctly
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", path);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "true");
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", fileName); // This routine prints a newline where fileName is supposed to be
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "false");
            fclose(fp);

            // Activate this for screw ups
            /*
            char command[PATH_MAX];
            strcpy(command, "cd ");
            strcat(command, path);
            strcat(command, " && rm abc *.finderDB .DS_Store");
            printf("%s\n", command);
            system(command);*/

            if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Path length has gotten too long.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            /* 
             * Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. 
             */
            listDir(path);
        }
    }
}
/* 
 * After going through all the entries, close the directory. 
 */
if (closedir(dir)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
            dirName, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}
```

Comment: This function is supposed to be `listDir();` ? BTW: I don't see any calls to opendir() or closedir(). Please post *real* code.

Comment: Just edited the posted code. Whole function block is there now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068475/recursive-hard-disk-search-with-findfirstfile-findnextfile-c.  An example that might help you out here with findfirstfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code I managed to fix. Still have no idea what the bug was but this should work on POSIX systems. Not sure about Windows. Thanks to alk for the initialization suggestion, xtof for chidir() (which i have still not implemented yet) and twalberg for explaining what chdir() does.

```
/* List the files in "dir_name". */
static void listDir(const char *dirName)
{
DIR *dir;

/* 
 * Open the directory specified by "dirName". 
 */

dir = opendir(dirName);

/* 
 * Check it was opened. 
 */
if (!dir) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
            dirName, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (1) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    const char *dir_name;

    /* 
     * "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". 
     */
    entry = readdir(dir);
    if (!entry) {
        /* 
         * There are no more entries in this directory, so break out of the while loop. 
         */
        break;
    }
    dir_name = entry->d_name;

    if (entry->d_type != DT_DIR) {
        char fileName[PATH_MAX] = "", indexPath[PATH_MAX] = "";
        if (strcmp(dirName, "/") != 0) {
            sprintf(fileName, "%s/%s", dirName, dir_name);
        } else {
            sprintf(fileName, "%s%s", dirName, dir_name);
        }

        strcpy(indexPath, dirName);
        strcat(indexPath, "/masterIndex.db");

        // We don't want to include masterIndex.db in the index list right?
        if (strcmp(indexPath, fileName) != 0) {

            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen(indexPath, "a");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot open file\n");
            }

            printf("File: %s\n      (FALSE)\n", fileName);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", fileName);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "false");
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    /* 
     * See if "entry" is a subdirectory of "dir". 
     */

    if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {

        /* 
         * Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. 
         */

        if (strcmp(dir_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(dir_name, ".") != 0
            && strcmp(dir_name, "tmp") != 0
            && strcmp(dir_name, "Jarvis") != 0) {
            int path_length;
            char path[PATH_MAX] = "", indexPath[PATH_MAX] = "";

            if (strcmp(dirName, "/") != 0) {
                path_length = sprintf(path,
                                      "%s/%s", dirName, dir_name);
            } else {
                path_length = sprintf(path, "%s%s", dirName, dir_name);
            }
            strcpy(indexPath, path);
            strcat(indexPath, "/masterIndex.db");
            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen(indexPath, "a");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot open file\n");
            }

            printf("File: %s\n      (TRUE)\n", path);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", path);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "true");
            fclose(fp);

            // Activate this for screw ups
            /*
               char command[PATH_MAX];
               strcpy(command, "cd ");
               strcat(command, path);
               strcat(command, " && rm abc *.finderDB .DS_Store");
               printf("%s\n", command);
               system(command); */

            if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Path length has gotten too long.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            /* 
             * Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. 
             */
            listDir(path);
        }
    }
}
/* 
 * After going through all the entries, close the directory. 
 */
if (closedir(dir)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
            dirName, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`system("cd any_path")` won't have any effect on the calling process; use `chdir()` instead..

Comment: The system("cd path") works fine in the code. I only uncomment the block if the function goes south and litters my home directory with index files. Thanks for the chdir() suggestion. Will use it in future code. :)

Comment: @NaveenMathew `system("cd path")` "works fine", that is true, but it does not do what you think it does. It starts a child process which executes your shell program, which then interprets the "cd path" string, changes directories, and then exits. It has no effect whatsoever on the execution environment of your program (other than wasting a little time...).

Comment: This answer does not do anything in terms of answering the OP's question, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing to initialise `fileName` here:

```
 char fileName[PATH_MAX];
```

Mod the line like this:

```
 char fileName[PATH_MAX] = "";
```

Not doing so could lead to access the unintialised variable, which is Undefined Behaviour and could lead to anything more or less rational or irrational.

Comment: still not working... it still just prints a newline where fileName is supposed to be...

Comment: I think I got it working. Still don't know what the bug is but I just went went around the problem another way. Will post my code once I am sure...