# List all text files in directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am trying to store the name of all txt files in a directory in a string and print them out. I need to count the number of txt files in the directory and then print the names. The part of counting is working, but I can't seem to get the name working. I have found some examples but they don't work in visual studio which is what I'm using.

Here is my code.

```
int main() {

    bool x = true;
    int i = 0;

    wchar_t* file = L"../Menu/Circuitos/*.txt";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

    HANDLE hFind;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

        i++;

        while ((x = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) == TRUE) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    cout << "number of files " << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yikes.  Can you do `Ctrl+K` then `Ctrl+D` on your code, then post it again?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **"I can't seem to get the name working"**? [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740(v=vs.85).aspx) have `cFileName`. Is it empty? BTW, you should check file attributes for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`

Comment: shouldn't it be `"..//Menu//Circuitos//*.txt"`?

Comment: Well the counter is working perfect. It is counting the number of txt files so the path has to be working.

Comment: The cFileName returns something I don't know how to convert it to a string, and only returns one value, but there more than one text file in the directory.

Comment: I don't like this: `(x = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) == TRUE`, it compares result of assignment operation and `BOOL` which I highly doubt is what you want. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068475/recursive-hard-disk-search-with-findfirstfile-findnextfile-c

Comment: The file name is array of chars: "TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH]". To convert to string: "std::string    file_name( FindFileData.cFileName );". Test it by printing:"cout << file_name.c_str() << endl;"

Comment: It display an error C2064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindFirstFile` already has the first valid handle. If you immediately call `FindNextFile` then the first handle is lost. The file count in your example would be wrong.

Use `do-while` loop istead.

Also, the handle obtained from `FindFirstFile` must be closed with `FindClose`

```
HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    do {
        wcout << FindFileData.cFileName << "\n";
        i++;
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
cout << "number of files " << i << endl;
```

Use `std::vector` and `std::wstring` to store the items

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

...
std::vector<std::wstring> vs;
HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    do {
        vs.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);
}

std::cout << "count:" << vs.size() << "\n";
for (auto item : vs)
    std::wcout << item << "\n";
```

For some older compilers `auto` may not be available, use this instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < vs.size(); i++)
    std::wcout << vs[i] << "\n";
```

Note, Windows API works with c-strings. In many cases you have to use `.c_str()` to obtain character array. For example:

```
if (vs.size())
{
    std::wstring str = vs[0];
    MessageBox(0, str.c_str(), 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Now it does give me the name of one file, but just one name. it should give me the name of all the files that finds in the loop.

Never mind, it works

Comment: Also how I stored in a string?

Comment: You can ask one question per topic.

Comment: It is stated in the main question "I am trying to store the name of all txt files in a directory in a string and print them out" but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portable version using the new `ISO` Standard [Filesystem Library TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) (technical specification) for those with compilers that support it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

// for readability
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

/**
 * Function object to test directory entries
 * for a specific file extension.
 */
struct file_extension_is
{
    std::string ext;

    file_extension_is(std::string const& ext): ext(ext) {}

    bool operator()(fs::directory_entry const& entry) const
    {
        return entry.path().extension() == ext;
    }
};

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // directory supplied on the command line if present
        // else current directory
        fs::path dir = argv[1] ? argv[1] : ".";

        // place to store the results
        std::vector<fs::directory_entry> entries;

        // copy directory entries that have file extension ".txt"
        // to the results
        fs::directory_iterator di(dir);
        fs::directory_iterator end;

        std::copy_if(di, end, std::back_inserter(entries),
            file_extension_is(".txt"));

        // print it all out

        std::cout << "Number of files: " << entries.size() << '\n';

        for(auto const& entry: entries)
            std::cout << entry.path().string() << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception." << '\n';
    }
}
```